# making assertions on a function parameter using AOP

Tags: java, aop, guice

How can we use AOP from the Guice library to make certain assertions on method parameters?

I implemented a `Vector` class for linear algebra computation.

```
class Vector{
    int n; // dimensions
    Vector sum(List<Float> v2){...}
    Vector sub(List<Float> v2){...}
    ...
}
```

The methods in Vector class normally take a List of float `v2`.
Before doing computation, I'd like to throw an exception if the `v2` does not the same dimension as the vector `this`.

```
  if (v2.size() != n)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("v2.size() should be %d, but is %d.", n, v2.size()));
```

I could copy the same code for every single method that takes `v2` as a parameter, but it's tedious.

Is there an easy way to do the same thing using the AOP feature in Guice? Something like:

```
 Vector sum(@Dim(this.n) List<Float> v2){...}
```

Comment: Did you read [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP) ?

Comment: If you use Guice AOP you need to make sure that all `Vector` elements are created by Guice. You'd need to prevent clients from creating new instances without going through some factory that Guice controls.